# ASP.NET: Global hook in Response?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there any way to intercept all ASPX Page Responses? I'd like to intercept all the pages served and inject a small JavaScript at the end of each.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with a HttpModule.

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Init is required from the IHttpModule interface
    /// see http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Appl"></param>
    public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication app)
    {
        // Wire up the Response filter
        app.ReleaseRequestState += new EventHandler(InstallResponseFilter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This article might as well (your javascript can be within the footer): 
[Add a header and footer control to all web pages in a web application, using HTTP module](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/headerfooter.aspx)

**Excerpts:**

> When developing the presentation of a
>   web application, we typically follow a
>   template structure for all the web
>   pages. The template usually contains
>   some sort of company logo and
>   navigation in a header section, and
>   some legal info and contact info in
>   the footer section, etc. The HTML
>   codes for these header and footer
>   section are typically the same
>   throughout the entire site, and may
>   therefore need to be copied and pasted
>   in every single web page. To avoid the
>   HTML code for the header and footer
>   section being replicated all over the
>   place, we use the "include" directive
>   to include a chunk of HTML code in
>   every page.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to adding a footer, depending on the details of your requirements:

1. An HttpModule.  Depending on how the HttpModule is registered, you may need to check for a text/html MIME type in the output, to be sure you're dealing with an HTML page.
2. A common page base class.
3. A PageAdapter that you bind to all pages.
4. A Master Page that you bind to all pages.